# Compare ids in Yii

Tags: php, yii

maybe this is a very basic question, but I want to make this comparation

```
$criteria->condition='id !=$id';
```

However, I am not sure if its working

Notes: the id is the id of my table, the $id is the one I want to compare

Comment: if you wanna use $id inside you string use " instead of '

Comment: but anyways this is not the best way to do this, you have  to use :param and add criteria params, also you may use addCondition() instead of the condition property to be able to add more conditions

Comment: also do not forget to use the table prefix usually "t" to avoid conflicts if there are more columns with the same name -in the join- so use t.id instead if just id

Comment: also you can use the method compare <- easiest solution 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail

Comment: Thanks I will try it, tahnks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You have used single quotes due to which $id is used as it is not its value
Try following -

```
$criteria->condition= "id != $id";
```

Comment: What is the difference between single quotes and double ? I believed they where the same, Thanks. I will try them

Comment: Difference : Single Quotes prints the string as it is without changing the variable(with Dollar Sign) to its value but in double quotes variable is converted to its value. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

More correctly:

```
$criteria->condition = 'id <> :ID';
$criteria->params = array(':ID'=>$id);
```

When you use "params" the value $id is screened by PDO. Also it does not matter what type of variable  is used. It can be integer or string value. 
Also this way assumed more performance and safely.